# How to set a composite background color for UITableView cells?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, calayer, background-color

I want to divide the `UITableViewCell` horizontally into two.

Set the bottom half color to blue and top half color to light blue.

Also the colors need to be reversed when the cell is selected.

I trying to implement using `CALayer`. But not much successful.

As table contain lots of data use of image will hamper performance and use lot of memory.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two UIViews ordered in the background and assign a different background color to each one?

Answer (score 0):

Create two `UIView` objects and set its background color to the ones that you want. Using these two view, create the background views for selected and normal state of the cell. You do this by setting the frames of the views according to the cell's frame. Then, you need to set two properties for the `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *backgroundView
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *selectedBackgroundView
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the background view property of the cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell = // ... code to create table view cell

UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2);

UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2);

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height, cell.contentView.frame.size.width);

[backgroundView addSubview:topView];
[backgroundView addSubview:bottomView];

cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```